# Is there any way to change og type from article to website without 301 redirect?

Tags: facebook, types, facebook-opengraph

Is there any way to change og type from article to website without 301 redirect?
I need to change it on main page of my site.

Previously my site had og type 'article' I change it to 'website' but facebook graph graph.facebook.com still shows "type": "article" and facebook developers debugger show error -- The object at 'http://exapmle.tt/' previously had type 'article' and cannot be changed to an object of type 'website' to avoid data corruption of existing actions.

And the question is how to change type in facebook graph?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change value, on specific event or at document.ready 
Try this jQuery code :  $("meta[property='og\\:type']").attr("content", "value");

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it is not suitable. Previously my site had og type 'article' I change it to 'website' but facebook graph https://graph.facebook.com still shows "type": "article" and facebook developers debugger show error -- The object at 'http://exapmle.tt/' previously had type 'article' and cannot be changed to an object of type 'website' to avoid data corruption of existing actions. I want that type was changed in https://graph.facebook.com :)